# Подскажите материалы по выбору роутеров (маршрутизаторов)

Tags: wifi, роутер, маршрутизатор

Добрый день !

У нас есть офис , и мы использовали для него роутер Wolflink WL0722. Он покрывал +-75 м2 с двумя не особо толстыми перегородками по середине. В общей сумме у нас 40 устройств (+10 телефоны/планшеты). Он с трудом справлялся , изредка зависал , но в конечном итоге перестал работать при dhcp , только при статике. Сейчас, мы хотим перейти в офис площадью 150 м2 со стеклянными перегородками. Подскажите , пожалуйста , где можно ознакомится с материалами по выбору маршрутизаторов ? На какие параметры ориентироваться , хватит ли одного (или нужен ещё один в качестве репитера), да и вообще. Спасибо всем заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117529/) статьёй, она посвящена как раз планированию wi-fi сетей.

От себя добавлю - возьмите 4 точки Uni-Fi и не мучайтесь.